# Lock screen from command line in Xfce

Tags: linux, xfce

I found [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/708065/lock-screen-from-cmd-line), but that's about Gnome. I couldn't find an answer about Xfce on Super User.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On my laptop (Arch linux + xfce4) two combinations work

```
$ xfce4-screensaver-command --lock
```

and the one mentioned by @Harm

```
$ xflock4
```

You can set a keyboard shortcut for locking the screen by going to menu

```
Applications -> Settings -> Keyboard
```

Then open tab `Application Shortcuts` and click on `+ Add`, enter any of the commands mentioned above and click `OK` (you will be asked to assign a keyboard shortcut to it).

p.s. Note that `xflock4` is usually available in keyboard shortcuts under `Ctrl-Alt-L`.

Comment: I usually _set_ `xflock4` to `Ctrl+Alt+L` but the default I've seen is `Ctrl+Alt+Del`.

Comment: `xfce4-screensaver-command --lock` works for me but not `xflock4`. I may have installed a custom screensaver or uninstalled the default one (can't remember).

Answer (score 2):

I found [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Xfce#Lock_the_screen) on ArchWiki. So the canonical way to do this seems to be:

```
xflock4
```

This is wrapper (run `cat $(which xflock4)`) that checks `xfconf-query -c xfce4-session -p /general/LockCommand` for the configured lock command and tries to run that. It also includes fallbacks to other access locking utilities.

Comment: And regarding other access locking utilities, here is [more from the ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/List_of_applications/Security#Screen_lockers). You can use pretty much anything, but it may be desirable to use something that doesn't have dependencies to a lot of stuff you wouldn't otherwise use. I use LightDM and so uses the accompanying light-locker.

Answer (score 1):

This seemed to work for me:

```bash
gsettings set apps.light-locker late-locking false
gsettings set apps.light-locker lock-after-screensaver 0
gsettings set apps.light-locker lock-on-suspend true
```

The simple way I found that was to enter in a terminal:

```bash
dconf watch /
```

Then make the changes in the GUI like all the tutorials tell you, and keep watch on that terminal.

The output from the terminal is:

```
/apps/light-locker/late-locking
  false
```

...which translates into the `gsettings` command I listed above. FYI value out of `unit32 0` means just input `0` for the final value, which is the second line with `lock-after-screensaver 0`. The `unit32` datatype isn't necessary in the command line.